# How to add linux headers to Eclipse CDT in Windows

Tags: c, eclipse, linux-kernel, kernel, eclipse-cdt

I was trying to code kernel modules (using pure C) in Eclipse via CDT on Linux Mint, but it seems the CDT doesn't detect the libraries. 
The libraries which are unresolved are :

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>  
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <asm/atomic.h>
#include <linux/list.h>
....
```

How do I get these libraries into Eclipse and make it detect it so that I can use them for development?
I generally use Eclipse for Java on Windows and it allows easy library importing, but I do not understand the CDT on Linux.

Comment: The standard practice on Linux is to use the 'kernel build' facilities to compile kernel modules; which may strike some as being 'too complex'.  Trying to accomplish the same thing using Eclipse... well.. lets just say that "you have a long row to hoe".  My advice, stick with 'kernel build'.

Comment: I can do kernel build and make files, but that hampers the development speed as Eclipse can suggest options for quick typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is flawed.  The question code lists several '#include' files, and call them 'libraries'; when in fact, they are 'header files' (not libraries).

The 'header files' all define symbols to the compiler which are resolved by the kernel when the kernel module is loaded (insmod, etc.).

The specific symbols, defined by the 'header files' are not part of a library that must be linked with the code (at link-time).  Rather these symbols are embodied by the kernel itself.  "The kernel -is- the library" (to be blunt). You will not find libraries to link the symbols in those header files.

I don't believe that you will find it practical (if even possible) to use Eclipse to build a kernel module.

Rather, use the kbuild environment supplied by Linux.  On your Linux system, read the file:

```
/usr/src/linux/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt
```

That will start you on the right path to building Linux kernel modules.

Comment: but how is it able to resolve some of the headers? (I am habitual of using java and hence end up calling them libraries) Is it somehow possible to copy paste them and force Eclipse to atleast detect them?

Comment: The path to the kernel header files is different than those used for userspace.  You can find them here: **/usr/src/linux/include/linux**

Comment: Even if I am not able to compile it completely, Eclipse really helps in the coding part and structural design.

Comment: What I don't understand is that I can compile and run the code, but the header file is not in the directory.

Comment: @chettyharish, you are correct; of course.  The header files are not in the current working directory.  Somehow, the kbuild system magically makes them available to the compiler when needed.  It sounds like you have some success with kbuild if you are able to compile and 'run' (or better stated: 'load') your kernel module.  Eclipse has taken you a long way; but when building LKMs, it's time to take the training wheels off the bicycle and really understand C.